# Control doesn't dock fill when full screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on a C# WPF application, and I'm trying to make the image1 control as dock fill when I maximize the main window, but what's happening is that the image1 don't expand to fill the window. I don't know how to fix this? Below is the XAML script used.

```
 <Grid Name="layoutGrid" Margin="10 0 10 0" Width="1847">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="342*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="142*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1363*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Margin="0,0,0,20" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="Images\Logo.png" Stretch="None" Margin="0 10 0 5"/>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="{StaticResource MediumGreyBrush}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="18">Basics</TextBlock>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="Images\Status.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 5"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Image Name="Image1" Width="640" Height="480" Margin="0,0,0,0"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Visibility="Visible" />
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Image Name="Image3" Width="640" Height="480" Margin="0,0,0,0"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Visibility="Hidden" Stretch="None" />
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2">
            <Image Name="Image2" Width="640" Height="480" Margin="0,0,0,0"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Visibility="Hidden" />
        </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

This is before maximizing the screen [image: before] and this is after maximizing [image: after]

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of what you actually see and what you want to see?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the questions was updated with screenshots added

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, the issue was Stretch mode in ViewBox. the control is occupying the desired space but view box was restricting it to avoid cropping. Fill will utilize all the space while cropping some part of the image

```
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Image Name="Image1" Width="640" Height="480" Margin="0,0,0,0"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Visibility="Visible" />
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Image Name="Image3" Width="640" Height="480" Margin="0,0,0,0"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Visibility="Hidden" Stretch="None" />
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2">
        <Image Name="Image2" Width="640" Height="480" Margin="0,0,0,0"  RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Viewbox>
```